# How to find outflow pressure/force of air through a pipe

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

I have been trying to find the correct method for determining the outflow force resulting from a certain amount of air being forced into a pipe of a certain dimension.  Essentially i'm trying to determine muzzle velocity/force/pressure.  I'm sure this is incredibly simple, but I have been looking around and cannot find the proper formula.

I essentially already know the length of the pipe, the volume of the air, and the diameter of the pipe.  I don't think i'll need this to be precise enough for temperature to play a huge part, though I'll assume room temperature if needed.  I'm not a physics person, so what I'm sure is a simple question like this is still outside of my abilities.

Comment: Im sorry if Physics.SE is not the correct place for this.  Also, it's not *technically* homework, more of a personal request, but I figured the question was close enough to what might be asked as homework to warrant the tag.  I'm really lookin for a push in the right direction, to get me started.  hopefully context is not needed, though I'll provide if needed.

Comment: It's not simple at all, actually, since the flow becomes turbulent for most reasonable speeds, dimensions, and fluids.

Comment: Probably the application of the relevant version of the [Continuity equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation) (which is the statement of mass conservation in fluid-dynamics) could help.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_flow

Comment: is it made easier if i'm mostly interested in the muzzle velocity?  i mean, there are calculations for that based on explosions and gunpowder, it should be roughly the same math, correct?

Comment: @acolyte; I did not understand your question. the force exerted by the air on _what_? if there is nothing to exert the force on, why will there be a force? now if we assume that an obstruction is in the way of the air, then there will be [Momentum transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_transfer) from the air to the obstruction. this force will depend on the pressure that the air applies on the obstruction. Am I going in the right direction? Velocity can be determined by continuity, pressure by momentum equations; or Bernoulli's, if the velocity is low enough (V < 0.3*speed of sound).

Comment: It's completely possible I am not using the correct terminology.  imagine that a projectile is being launched from the pipe.  i'm trying to figure out how much force it will exit with/what velocity it might have, though in a general sense.  i'm not factoring in the aerodynamic properties of the projectile.